# WSO2 ESB EntitlementMediator Error occurred while evaluating the policy

Tags: wso2, esb, identity, xacml

I followed [this guide](http://docs.wso2.org/wiki/display/IS410/Adding+Fine-grained+Authorization+for+Proxy+Services+in+ESB) to integrate ESB with Identity Server.

I tried by wso2esb-4.6.0 and wso2is-4.1.0

Following are my steps:

1. Configure the WSO2 Identity Server as the XACML engine and start Identity Server.
2. Configure the Entitlement mediator in the WSO2 ESB and start ESB.
3. Run the client code in IDE.

But ESB `EntitlementMediator` error occurred.

In ESB command window, following error occurred:

```
[2013-06-25 22:33:05,236] ERROR - EntitlementMediator Error occurred while evaluating the policy java.lang.NullPointerException
    at org.wso2.carbon.identity.entitlement.mediator.EntitlementMediator.mediate(EntitlementMediator.java:153)
    at org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:71)
    at org.apache.synapse.mediators.base.SequenceMediator.mediate(SequenceMediator.java:114)
    at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.ProxyServiceMessageReceiver.receive(ProxyServiceMessageReceiver.java:154)
    at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:180)
    at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.ServerWorker.processEntityEnclosingRequest(ServerWorker.java:434)
    at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.ServerWorker.run(ServerWorker.java:219)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.base.threads.NativeWorkerPool$1.run(NativeWorkerPool.java:172)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)
```

In IS command window, following error occurred:

```
[2013-06-25 22:33:05,063]  WARN {org.wso2.balana.ctx.RequestCtxFactory} -  No Namespace defined in XACML request and Assume as XACML 3.0
[2013-06-25 22:33:05,085]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.identity.entitlement.policy.finder.CarbonPolicyFinder} -  Initializing of policy store is started at :  Tue Jun 25 22:33:05 CST 2013
[2013-06-25 22:33:05,093]  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.identity.entitlement.policy.finder.CarbonPolicyFinder} -  Initializing of policy store is finished at :  Tue Jun 25 22:33:05 CST 2013
```

In client IDE, following messages occur in the console:

```
13/06/25 22:32:56 ERROR sandesha2.SandeshaModule: Could not load module policies. Using default values.
13/06/25 22:32:57 INFO tcp.TCPTransportSender: TCP Sender started
Exception in thread "main" org.apache.axis2.AxisFault: The input stream for an incoming message is null.
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.TransportUtils.createSOAPMessage(TransportUtils.java:92)
    at org.apache.axis2.transport.TransportUtils.createSOAPMessage(TransportUtils.java:67)
    at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.handleResponse(OutInAxisOperation.java:346)
    at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.send(OutInAxisOperation.java:413)
    at org.apache.axis2.description.OutInAxisOperationClient.executeImpl(OutInAxisOperation.java:224)
    at org.apache.axis2.client.OperationClient.execute(OperationClient.java:149)
    at org.apache.axis2.client.ServiceClient.sendReceive(ServiceClient.java:554)
    at org.apache.axis2.client.ServiceClient.sendReceive(ServiceClient.java:530)
    at org.wso2.entitlement.sample.WSEntitlementTestClient.main(WSEntitlementTestClient.java:59)
```

Does anyone know about this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is seems to a bug which is fixed in next ESB version(4.7.0). It will be released in the near future. See[1].

[1] https://wso2.org/jira/browse/ESBJAVA-1915

Comment: Thank you for you advice. But how can I get ESB version(4.7.0) to try with it?

Comment: ESB 4.7.0 is released... Check [1].
[1] http://wso2.com/products/enterprise-service-bus